# Need to pass the Rowdata to another view on link click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Here is my JQGrid Code:

```
click: function (e) {
                            debugger;
                            var id = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
                            rowdata = jQuery("#EmpTable").getRowData(id);
                            Data = { Id: rowdata.Id, Name: rowdata.Name, Designation: rowdata.Designation };

                            var url = 'http://localhost:50428/Script/Edit/';
                           return $.post(url, Data);

                                  }
```

here is my controller code where the data is collecting

```
 [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection form)
      {
          gridmodel properties = new gridmodel();

          properties.Id = Convert.ToInt32(form["id"]);
          properties.Name = form["Name"];
          properties.Designation = form["Designation"];
          ViewBag.id = properties.Id;
          ViewBag.name = properties.Name;
          ViewBag.designation = properties.Designation;
          return View();
      }
```

Now here is my View code

the data that is passing from the controller to the view

```
 @model MVC5_JQGrid.Models.gridmodel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
      Id:@ViewBag.id
      <br />
      Name:@ViewBag.name
      <br />
      Designation:@ViewBag.designation

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But i am unable to load this page but in network ---> Response body i can see that these values are assigned

**Update**

Hello Venkata thanks for the answer i will keep the points which you mentioned and +1 from my side for the observation ,coming to the problem. it was resolved from oleg suggestion:(Here is the answer given by Oleg) The reason of your problem is the usage of $.post(url, Data); which just send data with respect of $.ajax({url: "/Script/Edit", data: Data, type: "POST"});. You need to do $.submit instead. If you would use HTTP GET then you can just assign new URL which includes parameters to location.href (something like location.href = "/Script/Edit?" + $.param(Data)). In case of HTTP POST one need to build  with  elements which contains (or just have on the page hidden form with all required  elements with required name attributes) and use $.submit. 
Thanks for the help from oleg and Venkata

Comment: try removing the cast IEnumerable<MVC5_JQGrid.Models.gridmodel> and see if ViewData prints out the values in a div? That being said, I would use ViewModel class which has GridModel inside it, rather than using ViewData

Comment: tranceporter thanks for replying to the post, i have changed according to ur way but no luck still can't able to view the another view, i am still residing in the grid page

Comment: Please post the solution as a new answer.

Comment: Sure Please find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few Changes required in your code:

> **Observation and Notes:**
>   Before fixing, we should know few points here regarding architecture, control-flow and standards

- jQuery AJAX requests get response to its success callback handler(in your code you've missed success call)
- In success function We should build or append or set HTML to target placeholder tag in existing page (let us say you have div for Edit section like `<div id='editSection'>...</div>` in your jqGrid page. you should bind the responseView to editSection div)
- When we send AJAX request: In Controller.Action Instead of `return View();` we should have `return PartialView();`
- In your `view.cshtml` give preference to bind elements with `Model` rather than `ViewData`. You can get model to view if you do `return PartialView(model);` in the Action.
- Try to reduce usage of `ViewData` or `ViewBag` in `view.cshtml`. Also business logic not recommended in Views.
- Try to [Follow best practices: Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) (in your code change `gridmodel` class name to `GridModel`)
- By default routing url template will have `{controller}/{action}` (from your url `Script` is `controller` and `Edit` is `action`)
- Make sure that you're passing correct Controller and Action names (Is `Edit` action located in the Controller with name `ScriptController`?)

> **Changes in JavaScript JQGrid Code:**

```
url = '/Script/Edit/';
return $.post(url, Data).success(function(response){
           //response datatype can be JSON or XML or HTML or text (In your case HTML Edit.cshtml View)
           //update you target html tag with response view.
           $('#editSection').html(responseView);
       });
```

> **Changes in Controller:**

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection form)
  {
      var properties = new gridmodel();

      properties.Id = Convert.ToInt32(form["id"]);
      properties.Name = form["Name"];
      properties.Designation = form["Designation"];

      ViewBag.id = properties.Id;
      ViewBag.name = properties.Name;
      ViewBag.designation = properties.Designation;

      return PartialView();
  }
```

You can change above Edit Action like below if action require input parameters only id, name & designation

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, string name, string designation)
    {
        var gridModel = new GridModel();

        gridModel.Id = id;
        gridModel.Name = name;
        gridModel.Designation = designation;

        ViewBag.id = gridModel.Id;
        ViewBag.name = gridModel.Name;
        ViewBag.designation = gridModel.Designation;

        return PartialView(gridModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Venkata thanks for the answer i will keep the points which you mentioned and +1 from my side for the observation ,coming to the problem. it was resolved from oleg suggestion:(Here is the answer given by Oleg) The reason of your problem is the usage of $.post(url, Data); which just send data with respect of $.ajax({url: "/Script/Edit", data: Data, type: "POST"});. You need to do $.submit instead. If you would use HTTP GET then you can just assign new URL which includes parameters to location.href (something like location.href = "/Script/Edit?" + $.param(Data)). In case of HTTP POST one need to build with elements which contains (or just have on the page hidden form with all required elements with required name attributes) and use $.submit. Thanks for the help from oleg and Venkata